# trouble importing skllearn

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

Hi i have installed the Scikit-learn but i keep getting error msgs when i try to import the sklearn module. it shows the following msg. anyone knows what's going on?

```
import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "sklearn/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from . import __check_build
  File "sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    raise_build_error(e)
  File "sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 41, in raise_build_error
    %s""" % (e, local_dir, ''.join(dir_content).strip(), msg))
ImportError: No module named _check_build
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of sklearn/__check_build:
__init__.py               __init__.pyc              _check_build.c
_check_build.pyx          setup.py                  setup.pyc
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.
```

Comment: how did you install it? what is your operating system?

Comment: ran the setup.py script in a osx 10.6.8 after installing the xcode in the snow leopard cd, gfortran, numpy 1.8 and scipy.

Comment: I've tried via apt-get and it works fine. have you installed `python-dev` package in your system?

Comment: I dont think so. I was using the pre installed python version but i changed to the 2.7 one. What is the python-dev package?

Comment: `python-dev` package will install many C headers like `python.h` that many packages have been written in C for python can use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in your errors: `ImportError: No module named _check_build` in that directory it has `.c` file and it never compiled.

If you check [this link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn) you will see many parts of `scikit-learn` has been written in C.

So for installing this kind of packages , you need to install `python-dev` package in your system.

`python-dev` package will install many C headers like `python.h`.

So install `python-dev` package in your system and then remove and install `scikit-learn` package again.